# Odoo Rest-API Failing to authenticate

Tags: python-3.6, odoo-12

I created a rest-api module in odoo12 and am using postman to check the end points but i get the error below on attempting to authenticate user

No CSRF validation token provided for path '/web/session/authenticate/'

Odoo URLs are CSRF-protected by default (when accessed with unsafe
HTTP methods). See
https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/http.html#csrf for
more details.

- if this endpoint is accessed through Odoo via py-QWeb form, embed a CSRF
  token in the form, Tokens are available via `request.csrf_token()`
  can be provided through a hidden input and must be POST-ed named
  `csrf_token` e.g. in your form add:
- if the form is generated or posted in javascript, the token value is
  available as `csrf_token` on `web.core` and as the `csrf_token`
- List item

  value in the default js-qweb execution context

  - if the form is accessed by an external third party (e.g. REST API
    endpoint, payment gateway callback) you will need to disable CSRF
    protection (and implement your own protection if necessary) by
    passing the `csrf=False` parameter to the `route` decorator.

Comment: Which kind of request are you using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick but not recommended fix could be adding csrf=false in authenticating method route as they said in 3rd point not sure why not recommended but may make the route from web less secure but for API it's all good

```
from odoo.addons.web.controllers.main import Home
class HomeExt(Home):
    @http.route(csrf=false)
    def authenticate(self, db, login, password, base_location=None):
        request.session.authenticate(db, login, password)
        return request.env['ir.http'].session_info()
```

Comment: Am quite sure this can be achieved without necessarily setting the csrf to false...I appreciate your answer and it works but am looking for the correct way of doing it...

Comment: Yes there may but not according to documentation like it's say's in last point "you will need to disable CSRF protection (and implement your own protection if necessary)" also looking for a better way to handle this